Getting Saxonhe to compile in python under Eclipse
I'm having issue making python saxonche  classes compile
when I try to do an import for the PySaxonProcessor using
from saxonche import PySaxonProcessor

Im getting:
Unresolved import PySaxonProcessor

I did the instructons here:
https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html#!starting/installingpython
I tried the following but it did not help:
https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html#!starting/installing/installingWindows
https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/7701
I have downloaded the zip file and ran the setup.py using command:
python setup.py build_ext -if
Can someone help please?
Thanks

It's hard to help when you haven't even told us the basics, like what platform you are running on and what error message you are getting. The answer to the question "why is this so complicated?" is easy: because SaxonC is Java code compiled with GraalVM, with a C/C++ wrapper and a Python API. If you describe clearly and precisely what you did and say precisely how it failed, then I'm sure someone will be able to help.

I'm using Saxonhe 12 in Python basically. Initially starting using it in Visual Code and it appears VC is good in hiding the error because the intellisence doesnt auto complete basically its running. When I moved to Eclipse using PyDev extension , the editor is showing an error on the reference PySaxonProcessor saying its unresolved but the code also runs fine. So basically it sees the package in runtime but I keep getting the squiggly error line underneath any class Saxonhe class. the question is plain and simple how to get the compiler\IDE see those references. .

Hi, SaxonC is provided via python wheel. You should be able to install it with pip install saxonche

That is what I did but like I said despite the code runs , Im getting complie error on the import . why is that. can it be fixed ?
